# How to extract part of a held expression without evaluating it

Tags: evaluation, hold

How can I extract part of a held expression without evaluating it?

```
Clear[w]
Part[HoldForm[w = 3],1,1]
(* w *)
w = 4
Part[HoldForm[w = 3],1,1]
(* 4 *)
```

Here I would like to obtain "w" again, not its current value.
How can I extract the unevaluated symbol on the lhs of the definition, 
if the symbol has a value already before the definition is made in the hold form? "Part" seems to always evaluate the
extracted part of the held expression. Is there a way to prevent this? Of course the problem is the same when I 
extract part of the rhs of the definition or when I extract any part of any held expression. I would like to use
this inside of a function which takes as the argument any expression. This expression is then held and extractions made from it. 
So the solution should work without knowing in advance what the symbol on the lhs of the definition is and whether it is bound or not.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use Extract instead, e.g., `Extract[HoldForm[w = 3], {1, 1}, Hold]`

Comment: @CarlWoll, thanks, this is indeed what I was looking for. But this returns Hold[w]. How do I extract "w" from Hold[w], e.g. for printing it?

Comment: Perhaps you could use HoldForm instead of Hold?

Comment: Yes. Thanks again!

Comment: `w = 4;  Hold[ w = 3 ][[ {1}, 1 ]]`

Comment: @Kuba lol at how you always seem to know all the holy grail shortest one-liners. btw mine (modeled after yours of course) is slightly longer but produces the output i believe OP was looking for.: `w = 4; HoldForm[w = 3][[{1}, 1]]` outputs `w` BTW im still a novice but getting better every day and holding expressions unevaluated is still a mystery to me but i did study the docs for `Hold` vs `HoldForm`.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
Attributes@holdFormComplete={HoldAllComplete}
MakeBoxes[holdFormComplete@a_,f_]:=MakeBoxes[HoldForm@a,f];
w=4;
Extract[Hold[w=3],{1,1},holdFormComplete]
%//FullForm
(*w*)
(*holdFormComplete[w]*)
```

Note that `MakeBoxes` is also `HoldAllComplete`, so it won't allow `HoldForm` to leak no matter what is inside it.

Comment: Why not `HoldForm` directly? Original `Hold` is a weak link anyway.