# How to get the symbol name of a list element?

Tags: syntax, hold, symbols

Let's say we have a list `g` with variable `d` as its element:

```
Clear[g, d]
g = {1,2,3,d}
```

Now `g[[4]]` evaluates to `d`.
But after `d` is assigned, `g[[4]]` evaluates to `d`'s value.
But it seems like `g[[4]]` is still pointing to `d`:

```
In[48]:= d = 1

Out[48]= 1

In[49]:= g[[4]]

Out[49]= 1

In[50]:= d = 2

Out[50]= 2

In[51]:= g[[4]]

Out[51]= 2
```

So is there anyway to get the symbol of `g[[4]]`? `SymbolName` does not work in this case.
`SymbolName[g[[4]]]` results in an error.

Comment: Take a look at `OwnValues[g]` and `FullDefinition[g]`. The closest I can get is `Extract[First[OwnValues[g]], {2, 4}, Defer]` but I cannot take the `SymbolName` as it's wrapped in `Defer` and removing that will evaluate it as 2.

Comment: ^ that said, you can get it using strings `StringCases[ToString@Extract[First[OwnValues[g]], {2, 4}, Defer], 
  "Defer[" ~~ x_ ~~ "]" :> x] // First`

Comment: Closely related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181853/how-to-extract-part-of-a-held-expression-without-evaluating-it).

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the name using `Hold`

```
Clear[g, d]
g = {1, 2, 3, d};
d = 2;

o = OwnValues[g];
m = MapAll[Hold, o];
h = FirstCase[m, RuleDelayed[_, Hold[z_]] :> z, _, Infinity];
s = ToString[h[[4]]];
n = StringTake[s, {6, -2}]
```

> "d"

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[g, d]
g = {1, 2, 3, d}
Part[g, 4]  (* what you expect *)
Trace[Part[g, 4]] (* how it is produced *)
d = 4; (* assign value *)
Trace[Part[g, 4]]  (* now you get the evaluated part *)
OwnValues[g] // FullForm  (* examine the assignment result *)
Extract[%, {1, 2, 4}, HoldForm]  (* extract what you want *)
```

Comment: Hi, your output in full form is `HoldForm[d]` whereas the output of `SymbolName` would be `"d"`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Well, OP said "get the symbol" not "get the symbol name", although yes OP did mention `SymbolName`.  OP can choose.  It might be desirable to be able to `ReleaseHold` at some point. If not, OP can just apply `ToString`.